# Pulling a range of dates in access and skipping holidays

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to Skip holidays using VBA code. I have the code written and i have it work with the weekday so I am only pulling Monday Through Friday. The code is meant to pull Prior day totals so i am always 1 day behind but my problem is when there is a Holiday the code skips the holiday leaving it all 0's what i need it to do is negate the day all together.

The Code is going step by step through the code looking for how many records is in a range i am collecting 7 so far for the whole week, but if a holiday is included which there is a possibility we can have 2 holidays in a range it displays those days as records ( I enter empty records in the DB). is there a way i can just negate nulls and have it skip nulls in the database where weekdays should be or can i create a subroutine to pull from a table that has holidays on it and just skips those days still displaying 5 business days.

```
    Dim iWeekDay As Integer
 Dim sSQL As String

Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim objRecordsetConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordsetComm As ADODB.Command

iWeekDay = WeekDay(Date)



Set objRecordsetConn = New ADODB.Connection
objRecordsetConn.ConnectionString = CurrentProject.Connection
objRecordsetConn.Open

'Start new section Collections

sSQL = "Select CollDate From tblTXandVACollDist Where CollDate Between date()-7 and date()-1 Group by CollDate Order by CollDate;"

Set objRecordsetComm = New ADODB.Command
    objRecordsetComm.ActiveConnection = objRecordsetConn
    objRecordsetComm.CommandText = sSQL
    objRecordsetComm.CommandType = adCmdText

    'Open ADO recordset
    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.ActiveConnection = objRecordsetConn
    Set objRecordset.Source = objRecordsetComm
    objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objRecordset.CursorType = adOpenStatic    'Allows both forward and backward movement in recordset
    objRecordset.LockType = adLockPessimistic 'Allows records to be edited.
    objRecordset.Open
    'objRecordset.MoveLast
    'objRecordset.MoveFirst

If objRecordset.RecordCount >= 1 Then
            dCollDate1 = objRecordset("CollDate")

        Else
            Select Case iWeekDay ' This is if there are no collection totals form the table the report will search for the current date and then use the below case to set the days so all other information that is pulled in will match with the collection date.
                Case 2   ' This is if the current day is monday
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 3
                Case 3 ' This is if the current day is Tue
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 4   ' This is if the current day is Wend
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 5    ' This is if the current day is Thur
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 6  ' This is if the current day is Fri
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
            End Select

        End If

        If objRecordset.RecordCount >= 2 Then
            objRecordset.MoveNext

            dCollDate2 = objRecordset("CollDate")

        Else
        Select Case iWeekDay ' This is if there are no collection totals form the table the report will search for the current date and then use the below case to set the days so all other information that is pulled in will match with the collection date.
                Case 2   ' This is if the current day is monday
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 3
                Case 3 ' This is if the current day is Tue
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 4   ' This is if the current day is Wend
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 5    ' This is if the current day is Thur
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 6  ' This is if the current day is Fri
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
            End Select

        End If

        If objRecordset.RecordCount >= 3 Then
            objRecordset.MoveNext


            dCollDate3 = objRecordset("CollDate")

        Else
            Select Case iWeekDay ' This is if there are no collection totals form the table the report will search for the current date and then use the below case to set the days so all other information that is pulled in will match with the collection date.
                Case 2   ' This is if the current day is monday
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 3
                Case 3 ' This is if the current day is Tue
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 4   ' This is if the current day is Wend
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 5    ' This is if the current day is Thur
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 6  ' This is if the current day is Fri
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
            End Select

        End If

        If objRecordset.RecordCount >= 4 Then
            objRecordset.MoveNext

            dCollDate4 = objRecordset("CollDate")


        Else

        Select Case iWeekDay ' This is if there are no collection totals form the table the report will search for the current date and then use the below case to set the days so all other information that is pulled in will match with the collection date.
                Case 2   ' This is if the current day is monday
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 3
                Case 3 ' This is if the current day is Tue
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 4   ' This is if the current day is Wend
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 5    ' This is if the current day is Thur
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 6  ' This is if the current day is Fri
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
            End Select

        End If

        If objRecordset.RecordCount = 5 Then 'this is a test portion to see if i have to adjust the chart to make sure the chart works on an individual basis per day
            objRecordset.MoveNext

            dCollDate5 = objRecordset("CollDate")


        Else

        Select Case iWeekDay ' This is if there are no collection totals form the table the report will search for the current date and then use the below case to set the days so all other information that is pulled in will match with the collection date.
                Case 2   ' This is if the current day is monday
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 3
                Case 3 ' This is if the current day is Tue
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 4   ' This is if the current day is Wend
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 5
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 5    ' This is if the current day is Thur
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 6
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
                Case 6  ' This is if the current day is Fri
                    dCollDate1 = Date - 7
                    dCollDate2 = Date - 4
                    dCollDate3 = Date - 3
                    dCollDate4 = Date - 2
                    dCollDate5 = Date - 1
            End Select


        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought is you can do a query something like this:

```
Select MAX(CollDate) FROM tblTXandVACollDist WHERE [otherfield] <> 0 AND (CollDate <> (select max(CollDate) FROM tblTXandVACollDist [otherfield] <> 0))  )
```

Depending on what database you are using syntax may be a bit different but a query like this would tell the db to give you the last date that inst today where whatever field your looking to compare with is not = 0.

You can then then alter this to give you today-2, today-3, etc. which should cut out a lot of the logic you have had to use there. (could also use this query which may be easier for you to modify. depending on ur db)

```
Select MAX(CollDate) FROM tblTXandVACollDist WHERE [otherfield] <> 0 AND (CollDate <> (select TOP 1 CollDate FROM tblTXandVACollDist WHERE [otherfield] <> 0 ORDER BY CollDate))
```

and alter it to this to discount the last two days

```
Select MAX(CollDate) FROM tblTXandVACollDist WHERE [otherfield] <> 0 AND (CollDate not IN(select TOP 2 CollDate FROM tblTXandVACollDist WHERE [otherfield] <> 0 ORDER BY CollDate))
```

Comment: I am using MS access

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of holidays, you should be able to pull a count of workdays, say five, with a simple query selecting dates from yesterday and back, not of weekends, and not holidays:

```
Select 
    Top 5 *
From 
    tblTXandVACollDist 
Where 
    CollDate < Date()
    And
    Weekday([CollDate], 2) <= 5
    And
    CollDate Not In (Select HolidayDate From tblHolidays)
Order By
    CollDate Desc
```